# Angular 2 Validation in Table Row

Tags: angular

The basic question is what is the proper way to validate controls that are contained inside of a table row?  I have a set of html like such:

```
<tr *ngFor="let items of myList">
<input class="form-control" [ngModel]="item.foo" />
...
</tr>
```

Angular 2's form api appears to be geared towards an actual form instead of dynamic controls in a table row.  Is there something missing about the api or is there another way to effectively use the api in a table row?  If not, what's the best approach to achieve the same results?

Comment: just to clarify, using ngFor with embedded input tags tied to a model property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
myForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  let updated = this.fb.group({
    someField: ['myInitialValue', [Validators.required]],
    groups: this.fb.array([]) //Create empty array
  });
  this.myForm = updated; //Update it
}

arbitaryFunction() { //Call this whenever you want to update validation on dynamic controls.
  const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['groups']; //Fetch array to add to
  yourItems.forEach(item => { //Loop through your array of items.
    let group = this.fb.group({
    propertyOne: ['InitialValue', [Validators.required]]
  });
  arrayCtrl.push(group);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I ran out of time and had to roll my own to get the solution to the person that needed it.  To me it felt like it would have gotten cumbersome to manage the table rows outside of them being individual components themselves.

Comment: Haha cool no worries, well that's how you do it anywas, please mark as correct for other people.